# Images are not working after redirecting to root/ wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-404

I have problem with images on my website. I have installed wordpress in blog directory, co I could access my website like mysite.com/blog. I have followed tutorial on [this page Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory](https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory) (Using a pre-existing subdirectory install), to redirect it, so I have changed site address url in settings to mysite.com, add index.php to root and add /blog/wp-blog-header.php in this file… I also have to update permalinks and htaccess copy to root, with following code

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Now my website is working fine but images are not working. I can see them but after click on them it shows 404 error page. There is /blog/ in image url. If I remove blog from url manually, it shows page with image (lightbox is not working) Could somebody help me how to solve this? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'd try Better Search Replace plugin to change urls of images in database.

Comment: Maybe I will try, but don't won't to broke something in database... But images has correct address, I can see them, they have url mywebpage/blog/wp-content/uploads... but after click on it it open attachment page with 404 error, as it is opening 
mywebsite/blog/postname/imagename

Comment: @ vb381 You mean images inserted by WordPress text/visual editor?

Comment: sry, not sure I understand... New images that I have just add are working fine, but all old images that are pointing to wp-attachment page are not working
Now I have another problem, I have tried some htaccess rules and it was not working so I remove it. My website is now working as before I can access wp-admin and all setting except permalinks settings www.webiste.com/blog/wp-admin/options-permalink.php
When I click on this settings it redirects me to www.webiste.com/wp-admin/options-permalink.php
All other settings are working... any idea how can I solve this?

Comment: @vb381 Change name for htaccess file by ftp for htaccess_bak for example and than try to go to permalinks setting and resave them.

Comment: I have tried also to remove htaccess file, but still the same. After remove htaccess only my website is working but posts are not working (I need to save permlinks settings). If I add htaccess with code above website and posts are working. Wp-admin is working in both cases but when I open options-permalink.php its still redirects me to page without blog so it shows me error. Even if I manually add to url blog it remove it and redirects to url without blog... I don't understand why

Comment: @vb381 So you have your WordPress files in mysite.com/blog and you want to have on mysite.com/blog display WordPress?

Comment: I want have just mysite.com and wordpress installed in blog directory. So I have moved only index.php and htaccess. It was working fine except images so I have tried some changes in htaccess and now... everything is working as before but I can't access permlinks settings as it still redirects me... all other settings in wp-admin are working fine

Comment: If you have your WordPress files in mysite.com/blog and you want to display WordPress in mysite.com/blog it's not subdirectory install. It's normal installation.

Comment: I want just mysite.com without blog... using this steps
Using a pre-existing subdirectory install
https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory
it was working fine, but images not and now permlinks settings is not working

Comment: And how is your htaccess file look like in subdirectory?

Comment: like this 
`# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress`

Comment: strange, but now my perms options in wp-admin works... so I need to solve the first question how to solve that images.